# Is it NOT recommended to use variable outside the scope of event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For jQuery or Javascript in general, is it recommended to NOT use the variable if its outside the scope of the event handler?

Example:
Should I avoid doing this?

```
var $abc = $('#abc');
var $def = $('#def');
$('#myDiv').click(function () {
  $abc.show();
  $def.hide();
});
```

Instead it's better doing:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function () {
  $('#abc').show();
  $('#def').hide();
});
```

Comment: in this case, it's a matter of opinion ... p.s. jquery is javascript

Comment: haven't seen any restriction of this kind so far. its ok to use such code.

Comment: The first is more performant, as it only has to do the DOM lookup once.

Comment: The codes do different things. Saying you should use one instead of the other is nonsense.

Comment: @Oriol How are they do different things?

Comment: @JasonZ The first one creates the collections of elements at the beginning, and doesn't update them. The second code creates new collections each time. So if you are creating or removing elements with these IDs, the result will vary.

Answer (score -1):

Events handlers should know as little as it's possible about your code, and you should also write the less logic as possible inside of them, in the case you're showing it's not a good idea to use variables outside the scope of the function, due that as in any other function, if you miss that variables of your code, everything of your handler will be broken.

In my opinion a better approach will be this.

```
function doSomething () {
   var $abc = $('#abc');
   var $def = $('#def');
}

//Use .on method for binding events, avoid shortcuts.
$('#myDiv').on("click", doSomething);
```

Here the handler will call a function that has scoped variables, avoiding writing logic inside the handler, and in case you need to change the function call, you can replace it with other function call whenever you want, demonstrating that this code is easy to follow and mantain.

Comment: What's the point of the function expression? Just use `doSomething`.

Comment: @Oriol doSomething wraps the code avoiding having logic inside the event handler. That's the purpose of it.

Comment: `$()` will make a new call to jQuery's object constructor, that's not what I call "*Having the less logic as possible*".

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the point about Oriol answer, and you're right the question is so generic here that the code, tries to demonstrate other approach here, that's why I wrote "In my opinion".

Comment: @Oriol you were right, I misunderstood your advice, I've edited the code. Thanks!